# ComboBox Field of a DataGrid binded to an Entity database

Tags: wpf, database, datagrid, combobox, entity

I would like to make a two way editable datagrid with a **combobox** column.
This datagrid is connected to a .NET Entity Framework. How could I do this? Could you extend my code?

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE Languages(
    L_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    L_Name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Movies (
    M_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    M_Title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    M_Language_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT MoviesToLanguages 
        FOREIGN KEY (M_Language_Id) 
        REFERENCES Languages (L_Id)
);

INSERT INTO Languages VALUES('subtitled');
INSERT INTO Languages VALUES('synchronized');
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
...
<DataGrid Name="MoviesDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding M_Title}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Language" CanUserReorder="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Languages.L_Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    ???
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate> 
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
```

**CinemaViewModel.cs**

```
private CinemaEntities _Entities;
public ObservableCollection<Movies> Movies{ get; private set; }

public CinemaViewModel()
{
    _Entities = new CinemaEntities();
    Movies = new ObservableCollection<Movies>(_Entities.Movies.Include("Languages"));
    OnPropertyChanged("Movies");
}

private void Save()
{
    _Entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DataTemplate:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Movies, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}" SelectedItem="{Binding WhateverPropertyReferencesTheMovieNavigationPropertyInYourEntities}" DisplayMemberPath="WhateverPropertyInTheMoviesYouWantToVisualizeInTheComboBox"/>
```

Comment: I made this:
<ComboBox  
 ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Movies, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding M_Language_Id}" 
 DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Languages.L_Name}"
/>

But I got the error after trying change the value:
*deferrefresh is not allowed during an addnew or edititem transaction* 

What's the problem?

Comment: I don't think that is related to the combobox. Also, if you want to show languages in the combobox set its `ItemSource` to a list of languages, not movies

Comment: Also, displaymemberpath should a property name, not a binding.

Comment: Now, there isn't any error. But the combobox is just half working. I can select a value, but after that a red border appear:

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.LanguagesCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"  SelectedValue="{Binding M_Language_Id}" DisplayMemberPath="L_Name" />

*viewmodel:
LanguagesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Languages>(_Entities.Languages);*

Maybe the problem is the combobox set a language value (not an id). How could I fix this?

Comment: It looks right, you're just missing the `SelectedValuePath="Id"` part. Add that and it should be good.

Comment: It's finally done! You saved my life. I'm a begginer, but from now I can handle things like this!